# ProgressDialog style in non Android project

Tags: android, resources, styles, progressdialog

I need to use xml style for a **ProgressDialog** in non Android project (library for Android).

I've created a styles.xml in Res/values directory, and I'm trying to access my declared style from the code:

```
final ProgressDialog startDialog;
startDialog = new ProgressDialog(context, R.style.MyStyle);
```

where the context comes from an Activity (Android project)
but I've this error:

MyStyle cannot be resolved or is not a field

It seems that the resources are not visible from the code in non Android project.

Any way to solve this ?

Comment: There is a `style.xml` in Res>Values. Put your code there and then access  `R.style.MyStyle`

Comment: it wasn't an Android project, so I've created manually styles.xml in Res -> Values... but it seems to not work

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it wasn't an Android project"?

Comment: it's a library, java class files, not activities, not Android project

Comment: You're overriding a library, OK. Which one?

Comment: libstreaming... I'm not overriding it, I'm calling a method inside of it and I inserted a ProgressDialog

Answer (score 0):

Solved just adding:

```
import com.mypackage.R
```

instead of

```
import android.R
```